# How to unset the dashed line once I am done with it?

Tags: ios

Inside drawRect, I drew few dashed lines after setting the dash pattern etc.
Now once I stroke this path I need to draw normal lines, what should I do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sets the pattern for dashed lines in a graphics context.

```
void CGContextSetLineDash (
   CGContextRef c,
   CGFloat phase,
   const CGFloat lengths[],
   size_t count
);
```

Parameters
...

lengths

`An array of values that specify the lengths of the painted segments and unpainted segments, respectively, of the dash pattern—or` **NULL for no dash pattern.**

`For example, passing an array with the values [2,3] sets a dash pattern that alternates between a 2-user-space-unit-long painted segment and a 3-user-space-unit-long unpainted segment. Passing the values [1,3,4,2] sets the pattern to a 1-unit painted segment, a 3-unit unpainted segment, a 4-unit painted segment, and a 2-unit unpainted segment.`